# Bind Infragistics UltraWebGrid with Hierachical view to collection of objects

Tags: c#, entity, hierarchical-data, ultrawebgrid

I have a list of entities that i want to bind to my UltraWebGrid.
The Class definition of the entity has the following structure

public class Parent
{

```
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public String Name { get; set; }
 public IList<Child> Children { get; private set; }
```

}

public class Child
{

```
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
 public String ChildName { get; set; }
```

}

I want the bind the Parent to the first band of my ultraWebGrid and the Children to the second band. Can anyone tell me if this is possible without converting the object to datasets. All the infragistics examples use DataSets instead of entitylists.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source code on this page, see if it helps.

http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=5594

Looking at your code, you just need to change this line:

```
public IList<Child> Children { get; private set; }
```

to

```
public List<Child> Children { get; private set; }
```

and it should work.

Comment: it is not ultrawebgrid. It is ultrawingrid. Is there any thing we need to do in html ?other than setting relation ?